# Inline Editing with best in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I have a User Index Page, In that page I display a micropost.

One User have multiple Micropost.

```
UserId, UserName, MicropostName
  1       Lipsum     Loren
```

I want to Update **Loren** using Inline but it's not working.

I am using http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

I added **best_in_place** Gem in the Gemfile and follow require process but not working

Please Help Me.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: please paste some code and ask more specifically, I'm sure I can help after that :)

Comment: Are you still having an issue? Have the answer(s) below helped at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add best_in_place to gem file.

```
gem 'best_in_place'
```

next add this JQuery code  to Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

In view use best_in_place like this, here partner_info is field name

```
<%= best_in_place partner_info, :type => :text %>
```

and finally you should have an update method which will be called by best_in_place when the field.

```
def update

  @partner_info = PartnerInfo.find(params[:id])



respond_to do |format|

    if @partner_info.update_attributes(params[:partner_info])

      format.html { redirect_to @partner_info, notice: 'PartInfo was successfully updated.' }

      format.json { head :no_content }

    else

      format.html { render action: "edit" }

      format.json { render json: @partner_info.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end

end

end
```

Check this with your code.I hope this will help you.